# How can I split up resource creation into different modules with Terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I would like to split up resource creation using different modules, but I have been unable to figure out how.

For this example I want to create a web app (I'm using the azurerm provider). I've done so by adding the following to a module:

```
resource "azurerm_app_service" "test" {
  name                = "${var.app_service_name}"
  location            = "${var.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${var.resource_group_name}"
  app_service_plan_id = "${var.app_service_plan_id}"

  app_settings {
    SOME_SETTING = "${var.app_setting}"
  }
}
```

It works, but I'd like to have a separate module for applying the app settings, so:

- Module 1 creates the web app
- Module 2 applies the app settings
- Potential module 3 applies something else to the web app

Is this possible? I tried splitting it up (having two modules defining the web app, but only one of them containing the app settings), but I get an error stating that the web app already exists, so it doesn't seem to understand that I try to manipulate the same resource.

**Details on how it's going to be used:**
I am going to provide a UI for the end user on which he/she can choose a stack of resources needed and tick a range of options desired for that person's project, along with filling out required parameters for the infrastructure.

Once done and submitted the parameters are applied to a Terraform template. It is not feasible to have a template for each permutation of options, so it will have to include different modules depending of the chosen options.

For example: if a user ticks web app, Cosmos DB and application insights the Terraform template will include these modules (using the count trick to create conditions). In this example I'll need to pass the instrumentation key from application insights to the web app's application settings and this is where my issue is.

If the user didn't choose application insights I don't want a setting for the web app and that it why I need to gradually build up a Terraform resource. Also, depending on the type of database the user chose, different settings will be added to the web app's settings.

So my idea is to create a module to apply certain application settings. I don't know if this is possible (or a better way exists), hence my question.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Can you provide a more complete/concrete example of what you're trying to achieve here?

Comment: Sure. I'm creating some generic template that different consumers are going to use. They may have slightly different requirements. Perhaps one don't want app settings at all, where another one do want it, or one may need a SQL server and therefore requires a set of additional settings. Another example is WAF where one consumer may be interested in having some rule exclusions and hence need a configuration block for this purpose, where another consumer may not require this.

Comment: This process is going to be automated, so I won't be changing the template manually for each consumer. That's why it would be nice to gradually build up a resource depending on which features the consumer chooses.

Comment: It would help if you could edit your question to show how different people would want to use the module.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I've added the use case to the bottom of my question. I hope it is sufficient to understand why I need to be able to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The best way for you to do this would be to wrap terraform with a bash script or whatever scripting language you want (python). Then create a template in bash or python (jinja2) to generate the resource with whatever options the customer selected for the settings, run the template to generate your terraform code, and then apply it.

I've done this with S3 buckets quite a bit. In terraform 0.12, you can generate templates in terraform.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it correct to assume this means that it is not currently possible to achieve with Terraform alone? I read a bit about the templates in 0.12, and I've tried out the preview. I am not sure I am able to achieve what I want using the templates.

Comment: 0.12 dynamic nested blocks that supposedly can achieve the same https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/hashicorp-terraform-0-12-preview-for-and-for-each

Comment: I am not really sure how dynamic blocks solve what I am trying to achieve. Wouldn't it be a mess of concatenating lists and have all sorts of conditions mixed in?

Comment: Well, you can pass the settings into terraform, and using dynamic blocks you can look through them to create the app_settings block, customized per customer. You can even pass the settings as JSON and parse them with data.external

Comment: I apologize for the late reply. I'm not sure it would work like I would like. I don't think it's possible to build up app settings with dynamic blocks, but instead I would have to have the whole app setting map defined, as app settings is a block itself. I played around with the preview a bit trying to combine dynamic blocks and loops (using the examples they provide) with no luck either. Perhaps I should give it another try.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 5 months old but I think that part of the situation here is that the way you describe splitting it up does not exactly fit how modules are intended to be used.  For one thing, you cannot "build up a resource" dynamically, as Terraform is by design declarative.  You can only define a resource and then dynamically provide it's predefined inputs (including it's count to activate/deactivate).  Secondly, modules are in no way necessary to turn on and off portions of the stack via configuration.  Modules simply are a way of grouping sets of resources together for containment and reuse.  Any dynamism available to you with a stack consisting of a complex hierarchy of modules would be equally available with essentially the same code all in a giant monolithic blob.  The monolith would just be a mess, is the problem with that, and you wouldn't be able to use pieces of it for other things.  Finally, using a module to provide settings is not really what they are for.  Yes, theoretically you could create a module with a "null_data_source" and then use it purely as some kind of shim to provide settings, but likely this would be a convoluted unnecessary approach to something done better done by simply providing a variable the way you have already shown.

You probably *will* need to wrap this in some kind of bash (etc) script at the top level as mentioned in other answers and this is *not* a limitation of terraform.  For example once you have your modules, you would want to keep all currently applied stacks (for each customer or whatever) in some kind of composition repository.  How will you create the composition stacks for those customers after they fill out the setup form?  You will have to do that with some file creation automation that is not what Terraform is there for.  Terraform is there to execute stacks that exist.  It's not a limitation of Terraform that you have to create the .tf files with an external text editor to begin with, and it's not a limitation that in a situation like this you would use some external scripting to dynamically create the composition stacks for the customer, it's just part of the way you would use automation to get things ready for Terraform to do it's job of applying the stacks.

So, you cannot avoid this external script tooling, and you would probably use it to create the folders for the customer specific composition stacks (that refer to your modules), populate the folders with default files, and to create a .tfvars file based on the customers input from the form.  Then you could go about this multiple ways:

1. You have the .tfvars file be the only difference between customer composition stacks.  Whatever modules you do or don't want to use would be activated/deactivated by the "count trick" you mention, given variables from .tfvars.  This way has the advantage of being easy to reason about as all customer composition stacks are the same thing just configured differently.
2. You could have the tooling actually insert the module definitions that you want into the files of the composition stacks.  This will create more concise composition stacks, with fewer janky "count tricks" but every customer's stack would be it's own weird snowflake.

As far as splitting up the modules, be aware that there is a whole art/science/philosophy about this.  I refer you to [this resource on IAC design patterns](https://infrastructure-as-code.com/patterns/) and [this talk on the subject](https://www.thoughtworks.com/talks/infrastructure-design-patterns-xconf-eu-2017) (relevant bit starts at 19:15).  Those are general context on the subject.

For your particular case, you would basically want put all the the smallest divisible functional chunks (that might be turned on/off) into their own modules, each to be referenced by higher level consuming modules.  You mention it not being feasible to have a module for every permuation, again that is thinking about it wrong.  You would aim for something that would be more of a **tree** of modules and combinations.  At the top level you would have (bash etc) tooling that creates the new customers composition folder, their .tfvars file, and drop in the same composition stack that will be the top of the "module-tree".  Each module that represents an optional part of the customers stack will take a count.  Those modules will either have functional resources inside or will be intermediate modules, themselves instantiating a configurable set of alternative sub modules containing resources.

But it will be up to you to sit down and think through the design of a "decision tree", implemented as a hierarchy of modules, which covers all the permutations that are not feasible to create separate monolithic stacks for.

TFv12 dynamic nested blocks would help you specifically with the one aspect of having or not having a declared block like app_settings.  Since you cannot "build up a resource" dynamically, the only alternative in a case like that would be to have an intermediate module that declares the resource in multiple ways (with and without the app_settings block) and one will be chosen via the "count trick" or other input configuration.  That sort of thing is just not necessary now that dynamic blocks exist.